# Strange crash on selecting a UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I am getting an `EXC_BAD_ADDRESS` crash when selecting a table's cell which should push a new view on the navigation controller.

Here is the stack trace (the `CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION_` is always there):

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/71415/crash_threads.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/71415/crash_threads.jpg)

I strongly suspect the new code I have added to load the  initial data the app needs in a separate thread, partly because the `init` and `loadView` of the new view controller are being called and return fine. I am doing a `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and then load a view showing a progress indicator. `loadData` does a `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setupMainUI) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` when data is ready. The UI (table and all) is loaded fine, the fresh data shows up great; it's only when a new view has to be pushed that the crash happens. Switching views via tab controller works fine as well.

Ideas?
Thanks.

**Update**:

This is what I am doing to load the new view controller:

```
    NSArray *arrayForSection = [filteredGobos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
Employee *selectedEmployee = [arrayForSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (self.employeeVC == nil) {
    EmployeeVC *emplVC = [[EmployeeVC alloc] initWithEmployee:selectedEmployee];
    self.employeeVC = emplVC;
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:employeeVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: show some code where you create and push a new view. EXC_BAD_ADDRESS means you're trying to access something that isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overreleased an object. Your app is signaled when trying to release the autorelease pool. That means something in the pool already was released and dealloced before. Try Build&Analyse or NSZombies to find the problem.

I don't think it has to do with your threading, as want you mentioned there looks right to me.

Comment: That was it. Not a threading issue. I was releasing an auto-released  array in the new view controller.